# Heap Sort Get Parent

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heap

To get a parent of a node in a heap sort array, the calculation would be (index - 1) / 2.

However, assume each node takes up 4 spaces in the array. To access a record/node, I must access the first position of the four of that record. So here's an example:

If a parent starts at position 4, the left child starts at position 12 and the right child starts at position 16. The equation to get the left child would be `2*position + 4` and the equation to get the right child would be `2*position + 8`.

What would the equation be to get the parent though? I need one equation to get the parent of either the left child or the right child, the same way `index-1/2` does. Would that be possible? If I need two separate equations, that wouldn't work since I don't really know if a record is a left or a right child.

Thank you,

Comment: Erm, why would a node take 4 spaces? It takes one.

Comment: Because that's how I want it.. I'm doing a modified version of heap sort that you don't have to worry about its details.

Comment: But you're asking for help with the details ;-)

Comment: Not really.. Its kind of a mathematical/algorithm question regardless of how the details work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the first index (or, in this case, the first four indices) blank; this simplifies the calculations. So the root should be at 4-7, the root's children at 8-11 and 12-15, and so on. Given this, a node's parent is at `index / 8 * 4`. If you have to let the root be at 0-3, you can use `(index + 4) / 8 * 4 - 4`.

(However, you should consider wrapping the four related elements in a class so that it will be easier to work with them and you can handle a single array element at a time.)

Comment: This doesn't work. For the left child 12, `12/8*4  = 6` and for the right child 16, `16/8*4 = 8`. The answer should be `4` for both.

Comment: Also, I can't wrap the four elements together because I am dealing with bytes on a file.

Comment: In integer division, 12/8 = 1. So 12/8 * 4 = 4. Don't do algebra, do what the computer does.

Comment: @Nayefc: Like I said: if you have to have the root at 0-3, you must use `(index + 4) / 8 * 4 - 4`, and remember that an integer divided by an integer is an integer in Java. So `(12 + 4) / 8 * 4 - 4 == 2 * 4 - 4 == 4`, and `(16 + 4) / 8 * 4 - 4 == 2 * 4 - 4 == 4`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following [C# Min heap](http://www.firatatagun.com/minheap-implementation-via-c/2011/07/01/).

```
    public int GetParent(int i, out int index)
    {
        double element = i;
        index = (int)Math.Floor((element - 1)  / 2);

        if(index < 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return _collection[index];
    }
```

This works for regular heap impl.

you can see the rest of the [MinHeap implementation](http://www.firatatagun.com/minheap-implementation-via-c/2011/07/01/) here.

Usually, heap structure is backed with an array and interestingly, heap wants to start from Array[1](http://www.firatatagun.com/minheap-implementation-via-c/2011/07/01/) to make calculating parent and childs easy.

if you want to modify the child, parent as you mentioned in your problem, you should consider wrapping your 4 nodes in a node but keep how heap works the way it is

Comment: I am unable to wrap them in a class, since I am dealing with bytes.

Comment: @BrianRoach that may work for small things, but think about a huge in-memory ARGB bitmap with 4 bytes per pixel, it's not worth creating an object/4-long array for each pixel.